# how to convert jarray to list<>

Tags: c#

I have a JSON Array as follow:

```
{ "images" : 
  [
    { 
      "pid":0,
      "image_title":"this is title of image1"
    },
    { 
      "pid":1,
      "image_title":"this is title of image2"
    }, 
    { 
       "pid":2,
       "image_title":"this is title of image3", 
    }
  ] 
}
```

How to convert it into List<> ?

I try the following:

```
public async Task<Tuple<Models.User_Data, Models.Response>> 
test([FromBody]JObject _jo)
{

   List<Image> _images = _jo["images"].ToList<Image>();
    ...
}
```

but it gives me: "jtoken does not contain a definition for tolist"

Comment: Try casting to `Image[]`, not 100% sure though. If that succeeds, convert the array to list with `ToList`. You could also try casting to `List<Image>`.

Answer (score 2):

GOTCHA!

```
List<Image> _images = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Image>>(_jo["images"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 JObject obj = JObject.Parse("here pass your JsonString");
 var jarr = obj["images"].Value<JArray>();            
 List<Image> lst = jarr.ToObject<List<Image>>();
```